# wordpress url param redirect_to & reauth=1 detected as deceptive pages

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, google-search-console

Need help

After change my domain from without-www to www google chrome detect my web have a deceptive page, this is the links the I got from google webmaster :

```
http://www.domain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://www.domain/wp-admin/plugins.php&reauth=1

http://www.domain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://domain/wp-admin/plugins.php&reauth=1

http://domain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://domain/wp-admin/plugins.php&reauth=1
```

I have try to fixed the problem, using the solution the I’ve read from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-fix-for-sudden-redirect-loop-at-wp-login-with-reauth1/ . But, it is not success.

I have turn on the WP_DEBUG, but there is no error.log created.

Please tell me the other solution.